# Adding jQuery .click() after addEventListener() on same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add jQuery **click()** event after JS **addEventListener()** to the same element?
It does work when i put the jQuery **click() content** inside **addEventListener()**.
But it doesn't work if i initialize jQuery click() after JS addEventListener()

`document.getElementById("load").addEventListener("click", function(){//content})`
`$("#load").click(function(){//content})`

Comment: And why the mix of VanillaJS und jQuery?

Comment: @NickParsons OP's syntax is correct. It's native javascript in combination with jQuery. The native javascript part doesn't use `#`.

Comment: @adamnikk Please provide a [mcve]. The code you've provided works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/f6o2zp07/

Comment: @icecub I could've sworn when I first saw the question OP was using `$("load")`, it has been a long day I guess 

Comment: @NickParsons Haha it happens. OP says there was a typo and corrected it. You probably weren't wrong :P

Comment: @Andreas Is that a problem? At the end both are just Javascript

Comment: @MarcS. No problem in itself. It just doesn't make any sense to first use the plain DOM methods and then jQuery to do the exact same thing: add an event handler

Comment: JS addEventListener() is for dynamic creation of elements, meanwhile i want some animations using jQuery click() to trigger animations on same click

Comment: @Andreas that's right. But is totally legit to use for exemple the jQuery function on() and then use plain js inside right? Just to know, because there are some people who differ and just hate jQ

Comment: @adamnikk You are using addEventListener to listen on click event for element that doesn't exist in the DOM yet?

Comment: @DenisOmerovic It does exist in DOM

Comment: @adamnikk Ok then can you tell me what this means JS addEventListener() is for dynamic creation of elements? You can dinamically create element with jquery as well.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have only 1 click event and then have it call 2 functions? 1 for the dynamic element creation and 1 for the animations. Your code will be clean and makes a lot more sense than 2 click event listeners on the same selectors.